# typescript dynamic input attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Consider I have an input element to whom I am dynamically passing attributes

```
<input 
{...props}
/>
```

Here props may or may not include certain attributes for example

```
   <Input
        label="Searchable"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.searchable}
        onChange={() =>
          this.setState({ searchable: !this.state.searchable })
        }
      />
```

What is going to be type for my props above?

Comment: should be `{ ...props }`

Comment: Can you explain more? do you have list of props that you expect and out of them some may exist or may not? or props can be anything like a,b,c, then how you plan to use them in your component?

Comment: @PritamKadam Props should be attribute accepted by input component.

Comment: function parameters(aka react component props) is inferred from function declaration not usage

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly understood your question because of lack of details, but is this what you are looking for:

Here all the fields are optional, and you can modfiy their types based on your use case,
for ex,

- if label can be any one of A, B C then make it union type
- same for type

```js
type InputProps = {
  label?: string
  type?: string
  checked?: boolean
  onChange?: () => void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you are asking what type the object has that gets passed as probs on creation of Input.

In this case it will be ":any" or more specific ":object". Everything that is not a primitive type has the type object.

More details:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object

Ideally you create an interface for your Input class or function, you can still pass them the same way as you do now. You can also make certain props optional if they are not required.

Example:

```
//input.ts
export interface IInputProps {
  label: string;
  type: string;
  checked?: boolean;
  onChange: () => void;
}

export default function Input(props: IInputProps) {
//...
const label:string = props.label;
//...
}
```